# Turn-based game setting properties for playcards

Tags: java, javascript, function

I am programming with Java (server side) and JavaScript a card game and I do not know how to give properties (on server side) to every card that I create. For a match I need 20 different cards from a complete set of cards (52). Now I want that these 20 cards get a value (Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King) and a symbol (like Spades, Hearts, Diamonds and Clubs). How should I approach this? I thought using if clauses like I used on client side would be ok (JavaScript):

```
p.initialize = function (id) {

  this.card= new createjs.Bitmap(images[id]);

  // HEARTS
  if (id > 0 && id < 14)
  {
    this.symbol = Card.HEARTS;
  }

  // DIAMONDS
  else if (id > 13 && id < 28)
  {
    this.symbol = Card.KARO;
  }

  // CLUBS
  else if(id > 27 && id <42)
  {
    this.symbol = Card.CLUBS;
  }

  // SPADES
  else if(id > 41 && id <53)
  {
    this.symbol = Card.SPADES;
  }

  this.VALUE = id%13;
};
```

This is the way I did it on client side. Should I do the same with Java or are there better possibilities?

Thank you for advices!

Comment: I think this is more a question of where do you want your logic to be? In general you don't want to put the same logic in both the server _and_ the client. Does the client need to know the type of card? Can the client just get away with knowing an image of the card? etc. Good question, maybe you could also try the codereview stackexchange

Comment: @user1066946 the server sends to the clients the id's of the cards they have to create. On client side I do have all properties of the cards. After the player selected his favorite cards he sends back to the server the id's. Now the server does not know which value and symbol the cards have.

Comment: @user1066946 thanks for pointing me to codereview stackexchange! i will try it